# Comparação de data selecionada com a data atual JS

Tags: javascript

Eu já procurei na internet e aqui mesmo no site, mas não consegui encontrar nenhuma maneira limpa e que funcione para fazer isso.

Preciso que o JS compare a data indicada no campo (que vai estar em um formato *DD/MM/AAAA*) e compare com a data atual, caso a data indicada seja maior que a data atual de um alert.

Comment: tenta transformar as duas datas de DD/MM/AAAA para AAAAMMDD (sem / e na ordem) e faça a comparação normalmente AAAAMMDD > AAAAMMDD

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Você pode converter a sua data de `String` para `Date` e comparar com o operador:

```
var strData = "28/02/2015";
var partesData = strData.split("/");
var data = new Date(partesData[2], partesData[1] - 1, partesData[0]);
if(data > new Date())
   alert("maior");
```

*Observações*:

- No Javascript, instanciar um novo objeto `Date` com o construtor vazio (`new Date()`) resulta em um objeto representando data/hora atual.
- O segundo parâmetro do construtor da classe `Date` é o mês, que é indexado de 0 a 11. Por isso deve-se subtrair 1 o valor da data em string.

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente parceiro! Obrigado!

Comment: informação sobre o construtor `new Date()`, o segundo parâmetro (mês) é indexado em 0, ou seja vai de 0 a 11, por isso o `-1`

Comment: Boa, esqueci de comentar na resposta. Vou editar.

Answer (score 3):

Creio que se inverteres a ordem o JavaScript já faz o parse:

```
.split('/').reverse().join('/');
```

#### jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wfpzu1s5/

```
var str = "28/02/2020";
var date = new Date(str.split('/').reverse().join('/'));
var novaData = new Date();
if(date > novaData) alert("Essa data ainda não chegou!");
```

Answer (score 3):

Embora já tenham respondido, segue uma outra forma utilizando a função [**`isAfter()`**](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/is-after/) do [**Momentjs**](http://momentjs.com/) que é uma biblioteca Javascript para tratamento e manipulação datas.

```js
// 12/05/2015 é depois de 01/05/2015?
if(moment('2015-05-12').isAfter('2015-05-01'))
    alert("Yep!");
```

```html
<script src='http://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.min.js'></script>
```