# Jquery - Botar cor em borda de elemento HTML

Tags: jquery

Quero fazer com o  metodo prop() do JQUERY, com que a borda de um elemento campo fique com uma cor vermelha ao redor caso o mesmo sejá vazio ou a informação esteja incorreta, estou trabalhando numa função de data que compara se a data final é menor que a inicial, dai bota o foco naquele campo de data final para ser corrigido, como é mais ou menos o esquema de efetuar isso, eu tentei abaixo, mas não consegui o efeito:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Teste" id="teste" name="teste"  />

$("#teste").click(function(){
    $(this).prop('type', 'css');
});
```

Alguém poderia me ajudar nesse detalhe com algum exemplo, desde já obrigado.

Comment: Então vais ter 2 inputs certo? Queres verificar à medida que o utilizador vai escolhendo as datas ou quando tentar enviar isso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Os colegas já apresentaram respostas que irão funcionar caso você as implemente.

Entretanto fiz o código um pouco mais pertencente ao universo de sua pergunta:

Existem dois input `type='date'` o primeiro é preenchido com a data atual

O segundo é preenchido pelo usuário, e logo após a função `validacao()` é chamada, seja pelo `click` ou pelo `blur`.

**Código Comentado**

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

  function validacao()
  {
    if($('.final').val() == '') 
    {
    //Mensagem será exibida caso o input final tenha qualquer elemento vazio
      $('.notificacao').html('');
      $('.notificacao').html('O campo da data final está incompleto!');
      $('.final').css('border', '1px solid red');
      $('.final').focus();
    }
    else
    {
      $('.notificacao').html('');
      
      var vetData = [];
      
      vetData = $('.final').val().split('-');
      
      //Transformamos o valor do input final para um tipo Date()
      var dataFinal = new Date(vetData[0],vetData[1]-1,vetData[2]);
         
      //Comparamos as duas datas
      if(hoje > dataFinal)
      {
         $('.notificacao').html('');
         $('.final').css('border', '1px solid red');
         $('.notificacao').html('A data final já passou!');
         $('.final').focus();
      }
      else
      {
         $('.notificacao').html('');
         $('.notificacao').css('color', 'green');
         $('.notificacao').html('Data legal!');
 
      }
      
    }
  
  }


 // Pega o dia de hoje
  var hoje = new Date();
  var a = hoje.getFullYear();
  var m = hoje.getMonth()+1;
  var d = hoje.getDate();
  
 //Preenche primeiro input
  $('.inicial').val(a+'-'+m+'-'+d);
  
  
  //Chame a função dessa forma caso queira que a validação funcione logo após o input perder o foco
  $('.final').blur(function(){
  
    validacao();
  
  });
  
  //Ou chame dessa forma caso queira que a validação funcione após o clique em um botão
  $('.btn').on('click', function(){
  
    validacao();
  
  });
  
  
  
  
});
```

```css
.g{margin:5.5px;}
.btn{padding:5px; border:1px solid coral; width: 50px; text-align:center;cursor:pointer;}
.notificacao{color:red}
.i:focus{outline:none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Data Inicial
<br>
<input type='date' class='i g inicial' />
<br>
Data Final
<br>
<input type='date' class='i g final' />
<div class='g btn'>Testar</div> 
<div class='g notificacao'></div>
```

Preste muita atenção ao usar o `.focus` e o `blur` juntos. Caso o usuário não acerte a validação correta ele nunca conseguirá sair do input!

Link Útil

[Comparação de datas em Javascript](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/63508/compara%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-data-selecionada-com-a-data-atual-js)

Answer (score 1):

Pode usar o `blur`, ao tirar o foco do input ele dispara o evento, caso não passe na validação o input é alterado, exemplo...

**verificando se está vazio**

```js
$("#teste").blur(function(){
    if($(this).val() == false){ $(this).css('border', '1px red solid') }
    else {$(this).css('border', '1px green solid');}
    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" placeholder="Teste" id="teste" name="teste"  />
```

Answer (score 0):

Tente desta forma, você não vai usar o prop, mas vai resolver:

```
$("#teste").click(function(){
    $(this).css('border', '1px solid #f00');
});
```

o css do jquery como o próprio nome diz, ele altera o css do elemento.